# Cannot read Excel chart properly with intended line of code

Tags: python, excel, function

So this might be a simple solution but I can't seem to come up with it. When I use the following code I can open the file, read through it and do all the necessary functions, but if I use the commented line instead of the one underneath it gives me an error at line r = L[15] like it can't read it properly anymore. What can I do about this? If more code is needed I can provide it. Thanks!

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        file = input("Enter a file name: ")
        try:
            open(file)
            return file
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error. Please try again.")
            print()

def read_file():
    #fp = open_file()
    fp = open("Texas_death_row.csv")
    csv_fp = csv.reader(fp)
    data = []
    for L in csv_fp:
        r = L[15]
        g = L[16]
        v = L[27]
        T = (r,g,v)
        my_list.append(T)
return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `open_file` function is returning the variable `file`, that contains the *string* containing the filename, not the file object (file descriptor) which is what you can read and whatnot.

You should try something like this:

```
def open_file():
    while True:
        file = input("Enter a file name: ")
        try:
            f = open(file)
            return f  # Return the "file object", not the file name
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error. Please try again.")
            print()
```

PS: When you're dealing with files, don't forget to close them when you're done with them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, you were right. I think it's one of those things I'll get with more practice haha. Thank you :)

Comment: Sure! You'll get the hang of it! **:-)** BTW, If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to its left to accept it as the answer (SO netiquette> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)

Comment: And have fun coding!! :)